# M2 > Error using $this->__("")

Tags: magento2, custom, controllers

**In magento 2.1.X**, I am trying to append some text in my template file using a block within my custom controller. But i receive an error when doing so (my html markup is working just fine).

[image: error stack]

My block extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template and my controller is kept basic for the moment as I will build a form with it.

in my **template .phtml** file, this is what i try to do

```
<section id="careers-section">
    <?php echo $this->__('test'); ?>
</section>
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `<?php echo $this->__('test'); ?>`.. Use `<?php echo __('test'); ?>`

hope this helps you.

Comment: right, since the translation function has been added as a global php function instead of beeing a function of the abstract block in M2. See https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/functions.php